# Splitting a Wav File using NAudio removes 1 second from each part

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I am using NAudio to split a Wav File into multiple parts of equal intervals. I am using a version of the code available on Sound Code by Mark Heath:

```
 public static void TrimWavFile(string inPath, string outPath, TimeSpan cutFromStart, TimeSpan cutFromEnd)
        {
            using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inPath))
            {
                using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outPath, reader.WaveFormat))
                {
                    //int bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;
                    float bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000f;
                    int startPos = (int)cutFromStart.TotalMilliseconds * (int)bytesPerMillisecond;
                    startPos = startPos - startPos % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;

                    int endBytes = (int)cutFromEnd.TotalMilliseconds * (int)bytesPerMillisecond;
                    endBytes = endBytes - endBytes % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
                    int endPos = (int)reader.Length - endBytes;

                    TrimWavFile(reader, writer, startPos, endPos);
                }
            }
        }

    private static void TrimWavFile(WaveFileReader reader, WaveFileWriter writer, int startPos, int endPos)
    {
        reader.Position = startPos;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign * 100];
        while (reader.Position < endPos)
        {
            int bytesRequired = (int)(endPos - reader.Position);
            if (bytesRequired > 0)
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(bytesRequired, buffer.Length);
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is splitting the Wav file, but each part is 1 second shorter than the interval specified. I dont know if this is an issue with the code or the library itself. Has anyone faced the same issue? If so, was anyone able to solve it?

**Edit**
This is what I'm sending to the function:

```
    TimeSpan cutFromStart = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan cutFromEnd = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            cutFromEnd = totalTime.Subtract(interval);
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++)
            {
                outPath = inpath + prefix + (i + 1).ToString() + ".wav";
                TrimWavFile(inPath, outPath, cutFromStart, cutFromEnd);
                cutFromStart = cutFromStart.Add(interval);
                cutFromEnd = cutFromEnd.Subtract(interval);

            }
```

Comment: are you sure you're passing the correct values in? `cutFromEnd` specifies the duration to cut from the end of the file, NOT the duration to keep

Comment: @MarkHeath yeah 
     `TimeSpan cutFromEnd = totalTime.Subtract(interval);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect there is a bug in your position calculation.

But maybe you will find it easier to use this technique

```
using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(inPath))
{
    reader.CurrentTime = startTime; // jump forward to the position we want to start from
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(outPath, reader.Take(duration));
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Still can't understand what the bug was in my code. Maybe a rounding error somewhere?